# Extracting json from jmeter response using regular expression extractor

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

I got json response as below where i need to extract the description value for my next POST method :

{

"description": "thisisjson"

}

I've tried using "description":"(.+?)" to extract but it is not working and returning me default value of error. 
Any idea on what i missing ? Thanks 
[mySetting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFaRw.png)

Comment: Can you provide additional information on what extractor, the code or commands you are using? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're missing a space after the colon in your regex. This sounds like very much The Wrong Way and you should use a json parser then extract the value. For example your regex will fail if the description is "hello \"there\"".

Comment: hi @user1620443 , 
i'm using regular expression extractor previously , but now it works fine with Json Extractor and Json Path expressions of  : $..description instead .
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Regex Extractor:

- "description": "([^"]+?)"

And configure it like this:

[image: Regex Extractor]

But for JSON it's better to use JMeter core [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and enter:

- JSON Path Expressions = $..description

[image: JSON Extractor]

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON Path extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=JSONPathExtractor#JSON-Path-Extractor) for extracting from JSON response.

JSON Path Extractor configuration

```
Variable Name: anyString
JSON Path: $.description
Default Value: NOT_FOUND
```

Here is a screenshot from JSON Tester in JMeter

[image]

If you still want to stick to Regex Extractor than I guess what you missing is a space after : in the  Regular Expression.

Use the following

```
Regex: "description": "(.+?)"
```

Here is a screenshot from Regex Tester in JMeter

[image]

Comment: hi , i've just tried using Json Extractor instead
and it works perfectly with : $..description
thanks a lot