# How to Extract a specific value from this JSON response in Jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter, response, load-testing

```
{"SecureCustomerLoginFPinResult":"{\"Success\":true,\"AccountCode\":\"AC0717000251\",\"AccountId\":\"251\",\"FullName\":\"Asad\",\"LastLoginTime\":\"Jan 18, 2018, 12:16:19 PM\",\"IsFirstLogin\":\"0\",\"WalletAmount\":93982.40,\"SessionId\":\"efa02b314f\",\"ProfileImage\":\"\",\"NickName\":\"\",\"UnreadRequest\":\"1\",\"ProfileLevel\":\"0\",\"IsPinSet\":\"1\",\"LastName\":\"Akram\",\"CashDepositMinAmount\":\"100.00\",\"InviteCode\":\"https:\/\/test.keenu.pk\/keenu\/?Asad7207\",\"InvitePoints\":50,\"SignUpPoints\":40,\"KeenuCode\":\"trfhf\",\"DebitCreditFeeChargeInPercentage\":\"10.00\",\"CustomerState\":\"C\",\"BankCategoryId\":\"1\",\"IsNameVerifed\":\"False\",\"CustomerPoolBalances\":[{\"Amount\":\"83305.00\",\"CustomerPoolId\":\"499\",\"PoolId\":\"1\",\"Priority\":\"1\",\"ExpirationDate\":\"18\/01\/19\",\"AmountToBeExpire\":\"\"},{\"Amount\":\"10677.40\",\"CustomerPoolId\":\"500\",\"PoolId\":\"2\",\"Priority\":\"2\",\"ExpirationDate\":\"31\/01\/18\",\"AmountToBeExpire\":\"200.00\"}]}"}
```

I have want to extract 'SessionId' from this JSON response using JSON Extractor in Jmeter. I have tried multiple path expressions but with no success. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe show us what you have tried.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986944/extracting-json-from-jmeter-response-using-regular-expression-extractor

Comment: try `$.SecureCustomerLoginFPinResult.SessionId` using JSON Extractor http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the SessionId value using [Regular expression extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) with the below configurations:

- **Reference Name:** MyVar //The name of the variable which will hold the extracted value.
- **Regular expression:** `\\"SessionId\\":\\"(.*?)\\"`
- **Template:** $1$
- **Match No:** 1
- **Default value:** NOT_FOUND

Reference:

[Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)